# No Errors but no speed increase using sunspot gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sunspot, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

I ran speed tests comparing the results between the traditional `Post.all(...)` and Sunspot's `Post.search(...)` against a table with about 3000 records. In both cases, it takes 12 seconds to load. Everything seems to work, execept any improvement in speed.

Env: Ruby 1.8.7, Rails 2.3.14

Sunspot.yml:

```
production:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8984
    log_level: FINEST
    auto_commit_after_request: false

development:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8982
    log_level: INFO
    auto_commit_after_request: false
test:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8981
    log_level: WARNING
    auto_commit_after_request: false
```

Gemfile:

```
gem "rsolr", "0.12.1"
gem "sunspot", "1.2.1"
gem "sunspot_solr", "1.3.1"
gem "sunspot_rails", "1.2.1"
```

Controller:

```
 @users = User.search do
    with :client_id, current_user.client.id
    paginate :page => params[:page] if params[:page]
    paginate :page => 1 if not params[:page]
    paginate :per_page => PAGINATION_COUNT
 end
```

View:

```
concat will_paginate(@users)
```

I suspect I've overlooked something quite fundamental?

Comment: Solr server has been started, restarted, and re-indexed. File sizes in the solr folder of the rails root indicate indexing was successful I assume?. Same speed though.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to load all 3000 posts? That benchmark doesn't make sense. If you have to load the entire table it will not make any difference if you're using Solr.

Comment: I absolutely don't want to load the entire table. I thought thats what pagination was all about. What can I do to only load the 30 records per page per PAGINATION_COUNT. From what it looks like, it downloads everything in the table. When will_paginate didn't seem to solve this, I turned to sunspot. Like I say, I'm not getting something very fundamental.

Comment: You say it's taking 12 seconds to load a page with 30 records in the first case: are you using will_paginate to paginate with activerecord? You can also use it in combination with Solr.

Comment: Same results with Solr pagination.

Answer (score 0):

Whitespace is significant in YAML. Are you sure the `auto_commit_after_request` line belongs under `solr`? I've seen [a few](http://outoftime.github.com/sunspot/rails/docs/classes/Sunspot/Rails/Configuration.html) [examples](https://github.com/mauricio/sunspot_tutorial/blob/master/config/sunspot.yml) where it falls under the development/production/test element:

```
development:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8983
    log_level: INFO
  auto_commit_after_request: false
```